# Can my companions equip Alignment Restricted items that I can't equip?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Seeing as I'm playing an Imperial, *there's a lot* of Red Color Crystals floating around. But I'm a pretty tolerant dude, and have hit a rank of Light IV.

All well and good, but I've recently started giving my companions customizable gear, since, as a Cybertech, that's easier for me to keep upgraded, but I'm stymied by color crystals. Will my companions be able to equip and benefit from gear with alignment restrictions? We know they [don't have alignments of their own](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45067/can-companions-have-their-own-light-dark-side-rating) in spite of a display bug, but can they equip restricted items in spite of that? If so, do they inherit the alignment and restrictions of the PC, or can they just use anything?

Comment: Try a low level (cheap) crystal and let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with late beta, companions share your alignment. I remember I switched from neutral to full light, and suddenly a bunch of items my companions were using couldn't be used anymore since they said 'forbidden for light I and above', even though it was my companions who were using them